# Differentiation when there are continuously many variables

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Suppose there are a continuum of tasks in a unit range $[0, 1]$, and for each task $i \in [0, 1]$, a firm can choose the amount of robots, $x_i$.  I am hoping to get the first-order condition (e.g., $\partial f(x, y) / \partial x = 0)$ for the following profit function of a final good producer:
$$Y-w_{N} N -w_{n} \int_{m}^{1} n_{i} d i-\left(1+\tau_{x}\right) \phi \int_{m}^{1} x_i d i, $$
where the variables are non-routine worker amount, $N$, robots amount, $x_i$ for $i\in [0, m]$ ($m$ is a constant), and routine worker amount, $n_i$ for $i\in (m, 1]$, and where the production function, $Y$, is
$$ 
Y=A\left[\int_{0}^{m} x_{i}^{\frac{\rho-1}{\rho}} d i+\int_{m}^{1} n_{i}^{\frac{\rho-1}{\rho}} d i\right]^{\frac{\rho}{\rho-1}(1-\alpha)} N_{n}^{\alpha}, \quad \alpha \in(0,1), \rho \in[0, \infty).
$$
The rest like $\tau_x$ and $\phi$ are all constants.

I am hoping to derive the first-order condition with respect to $x_i$ for $i \in [0, m]$--i.e., take the partial derivative of the first equation with respect to $x_i$ for $i \in [0, m]$. 
The answer "seemingly" has to be
$$
\left(1+\tau_{x}\right) \phi=(1-\alpha) Y\left(\int_{0}^{m} x_{s}^{\frac{\rho-1}{\rho}} d s+\int_{m}^{1} n_{s}^{\frac{\rho-1}{\rho}} d s\right)^{-1} x_{i}^{-\frac{1}{\rho}}, \text { for } i \in[0, m].
$$

However, what I am getting is, for $i \in [0, m]$ (which I interpreted as, "for some fixed $i$"),
$$
\left(1+\tau_{x}\right) \phi = \left(\frac{(1 - \alpha) n_i^{1/\rho }}{n_i x_i^{1/\rho }+x_i n_i^{1/\rho }}\right) \left.A \left(x_i^{\frac{-1+\rho }{\rho }}+n_i^{\frac{-1+\rho }{\rho }}\right)^{\frac{(1-\alpha ) \rho }{-1+\rho }} N^{\alpha }\right).
$$

I did not even get an integral since I thought, as soon as I fix $i$, there is nothing to integrate in the first place.

What am I missing? Or is the answer incorrect?

Comment: Sorry I edited the last equation since it was wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I figured it out. Rather than fixing $i$, taking the partial derivative of the profit function with respect to $x_i$ directly made it sense that the final equation has integrals and the form in the answer.